# MS Access - storing calculated field from a form in a table

Tags: forms, ms-access

I have a textbox in a form that I created.

I want to add an expression in the textbox's Control Source property. I also want to bind the textbox to a field in the table using Control Source propety of the textbox.

Is there any way I can add a field name and an expression in the control source property of a particular textbox?

The expression sums up the total amount a customer must pay based on the price and amount.

I tried solving this problem by looking at solutions on stackoverflow from people with the same problem but that didnt work for me either.
I know that storing calculated fields is bad, but I have to do it.

Comment: All you need is to add that calculated field to your table. Not recommended, true, but thats how to do it. Then bind your textbox to this field.

Comment: I already have a field in a table in which I want to store the value of a textbox but the problem is that it doesnt because the textbox isnt bound to the field (cant be bound) because I am using control source to calculate the total. Is there another way to bound the textbox to a table field?

Comment: Replace that field with a calculated field using the expression you currently use as control source for the textbox. Then bind the textbox to the field, and any update will happen automatically.

Comment: If you mean in a table, I cant because the quantity is a field of one table and the cost of each item is a field in another table. Thats why this is causing me so much problem. I have 2 fields from two different tables.

Comment: Then I would create a query that joins the two tables and includes the calculation. Then use this as source for the form and bind the textbox to the calculated field. No updates needed.

Comment: You would only save either the price or the calculated result if the price could change over time and don't want old records to reflect new price. Better to save the raw price value than the calculated result. Either requires code (macro or VBA) to save. Alternative is to create new product record when price changes and flag old record as "Inactive" and not allow for selection in new transactions.

Comment: When I try to use the query as a control source for the textbox and when I run the form, it says: #Name? inside the textbox